# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch when trying to "accumulate" results

Tags: matlab

I want to accumulate kmeans results in a matrix.

This is my code:

```
for i=1:10
    test(i,:) = kmeans(C,2);
end
```

I want replace this code with a "one-liner" (vectorise?).

I tried the following:

```
test(1:10,:) = kmeans(C,2);
```

And get the above error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The problem is you'll have to call `kmeans` 10 times anyway. I'm not sure you can vectorise that. `kmeans` has a `replicates` parameter where you set the number of times you want to run the clustering (from scratch). But it will only return the 'best' cluster, acording to a criteria. Perhaps you could modify `kmeans.m` to make it return all the clusters, and call the function with `replicates` = 10.

Comment: @RTL 1) i want to accumulate different results of kmeans in one matrix  2) running your snippet produces the same error for me.

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment as it was incorrect and not worth editing to salvage, short of changing the `kmeans` function I cant see an obvious way to do this